# Изменяя значение DataGrid в другом потоке

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность, datagrid

Есть `DataGrid`, в него заношу новый объект. Если я в основном потоке получаю ссылку на первый `Item` у `DataGrid`, привожу его к типу и изменяю свойства, то и значения в таблице тоже меняются. Но если же я создаю новый поток и в нем проделываю тоже самое, ничего не получается. Даже если я проделываю это через `BeginInvoke`

```
RobotsInfo ri = (RobotsInfo)dataGrid.Items[0];
ri.Name = "AAA";
```

Данный код в основном потоке изменяет значение в таблице на `AAA`, а если сделать тоже самое в другом потоке, то ничего не получается. Как можно решить это?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попросите `Dispatcher` выполнить эти действия в "правильном" потоке:

```
dataGrid.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        RobotsInfo ri = (RobotsInfo)dataGrid.Items[0];
        ri.Name = "AAA";
    });
```

Comment: Не работает в итоге. Проверил свой код в простой функции нажатия на кнопку в основном потоке, всё изменяет. Тоже самое кидаю в другую функцию с привязкой к Dispatcher и ничего не происходит.

Comment: А код из лямбды точно выполняется? Точку останова в него поместите, проверьте

Comment: Код из лямбды выполняется, проверил. Возможно я значение dataGrid.Items изменяю каким-то не таким способом, но в основном потоке этот код работает и таблицу изменяет.

Comment: Возможно именно из-за того, что ссылка на данный объект куда-то теряется во втором потоке и её изменение не дает изменению реальной ссылки у DataGrid. Потому что, например, удалить из dataGrid items получается, т.е. мы в основном потоке всё выполняем, но именно данный код не работает.

Comment: Кстати, а если вызвать еще дополнительно `dataGrid.Items.Refresh()`?

Comment: Да, всё заработало) Спасибо большое, про диспатчер знал еще давно, но рефреш не использовал)

Comment: Ну я вам рекомендую познакомиться уже с привязками и MVVM

Comment: Сейчас проект, который нужны в течении 2 месяцев выполнить, поэтому приходится часто спрашивать здесь. А так, жду уже, когда смогу изучить углубленно программирование, книги уже есть по совету)

Answer (score 3):

В .NET Доступ к UI потоку ограничен в целях безопасности. Поэтому нужно использовать диспетчер.

Ниже приведён пример, как можно выполнить операции с UI в требуемом потоке.

```
// Создаём и запускаем поток.
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(UpdateTextWrong);
    thread.Start();
}
// Метод, который будет выполняться в потокею
private void UpdateTextWrong()
{
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
        (ThreadStart)delegate()
        {
           // Делаем что-то в UI-потоке.
        }
        );
}
```

Comment: Тоже не работает, добавил всё так, как вы указали. Аналогичный код в основном потоке изменяет данные в таблице, а в дополнительном нет.

Comment: Значит где-то ошиблись при копировании или доработке моего примера под свою задачу. Я этот пример проверял (.NET 4.6.1 VS 2017).